# After chrome update to version 87.0.4280.141 getting error "Driver info: driver.version: unknown"

Tags: protractor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPJQu.png)

i have tried "npm install chromedriver",still its not working for me.
Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the chromedriver from here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=87.0.4280.88/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using chromedriver with selenium, u can try updating your selenium version. That might help !!!